# Can I make image upload faster using base64 encoding in android?

Tags: android, upload, base64, multipartentity

I need to upload an image from my android application to php server.I am using multipart entity to send image.If I upload the image by encoding using [base 64](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) will it improve the performance.Any idea please help?

Comment: In simple words no, base64 images actually take more time to upload comparing to the file upload, this is because base64 strings are 30-34% bigger comparing to real file size

Answer (score 4):

As with any performance questions, empirical measurement is king.

As an educated guess, I predict base64-encoded upload to take approximately 33% more time compared to binary transfer as each byte in a base64-encoded message only carries 6 bits of payload.